# i am looking for a help desk solutions open source

Tags: open-source, tool-rec

i am looking for a help desk solution i want it open source to developing, i can payment if there was.
can someone help me to search about this.

[some features I want here](http://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/help-desk-features.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [osTicket](http://osticket.com/). You can edit it all you like :)